# How can I inject IServiceProvider into a WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, vsix

I am writing a VSIX project which shows a tree view of files in the solution (like Solution Explorer).

I now need to show the relevant icon for the project item (.cs file, etc), and have the following code.

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer;

public partial class VSIconControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileExtensionProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("FileExtension", typeof(string), typeof(VSIconControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnFileExtensionChanged));

    public VSIconControl(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateIcon();
    }

    public string FileExtension
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FileExtensionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileExtensionProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnFileExtensionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as VSIconControl;
        control?.UpdateIcon();
    }

    private void UpdateIcon()
    {
        string fileExtension = FileExtension;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension))
        {
            // If no file extension is provided, use the folder icon
            fileExtension = "folder";
        }

        ImageSource imageSource = GetImageForFileExtension(ServiceProvider, fileExtension);
        IconImage.Source = imageSource;
    }

    private ImageSource GetImageForFileExtension(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string fileExtension)
    {
        ImageMoniker moniker = GetImageMonikerForFileExtension(serviceProvider, fileExtension);
        ImageSource image = GetImageForMoniker(serviceProvider, moniker);
        return image;
    }

    private ImageMoniker GetImageMonikerForFileExtension(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string fileExtension)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

        IVsImageService2 imageService = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsImageService)) as IVsImageService2;
        if (imageService == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to get IVsImageService2.");
        }

        // Get the ImageMoniker for the given file extension
        ImageMoniker moniker = imageService.GetImageMonikerForFile(fileExtension);
        return moniker;
    }

    private ImageSource GetImageForMoniker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ImageMoniker moniker)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

        IVsImageService2 imageService = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsImageService)) as IVsImageService2;
        if (imageService is null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to get IVsImageService2.");

        // Get the actual image for the moniker
        object image = imageService.GetImage(moniker, new ImageAttributes());
        return image as ImageSource;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this component like so:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <featureui:VSIconControl FileExtension=".cs"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But this doesn't work because `VSIconControl` doesn't have a parameterless constructor. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score -1):

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider`